# Python Priority Queue, insertion of elements

Tags: python, class, sorting, queue

I am making a class that is a priority Queue.
My queue contains of a list with paired tuples:

```
[("do my homework", 1), ("clean my room", 2)]
```

and I am trying to make a function inside my class that will insert an element (tuple) in the Queue (list). If the inserted tuple has higher priority (greater number to the right) than the one already in the Queue, then the tuple with higher priority will be inserted before the tuple with lower.

So a correct order will be:

```
[("make food", 4), ("clean my room", 2),("do my homework", 1)]
```

I think I have to do some kind of sorting function and I have started to make one but I am stuck.

```
self.item = []

def enqueue(self, a, b):
    for el in self.item:
        if self.item.empty():
            return self.item.insert(0, (a, b))
        else:
            for tupl in el:
                if tupl[1] > tupl+1[1]:
```

Comment: Assume the Queue is already sorted.  Go through the elements until you find one with lower priority.  Insert before that element.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, Python has a Priority queue already implemented: https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue